# onchange event not firing on <select> element

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am trying to call `show()` when the select dropdown changes, but the event is not firing.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function show() { 
        alert(document.getElementById("start").value); 
    } 
</script>

<div class="side-by-side clearfix" style="margin-bottom:14px;">
    <select  data-placeholder="Select Loacation" class="chzn-select" tabindex="2" name="source" id="start" onchange="show()">
      <option value="">Select Loacation</option>
      <c:forEach items="${listOfRoutes}" var = "route">
      <option value="${route.source }" >${route.source }</option>
      </c:forEach>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) please.

Answer (score 1):

Your html syntax is fine, so there could be an error with the show function. Check your console to make sure.

Edit: The event is fired on my end... hmm...

Comment: My best guess is something to do with one of the frameworks you're using. Try creating an html file with just this code. Also, have you checked your console?

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine. I think your getElementById fails to fetch what you want.

Here a small working example of what you want - but as stated. Your syntax looks fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript">        
  function hello() 
  {
    alert("hello");
  }
</script>

<select id="Select1" onchange="hello()">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: its working fine if i remove the css class to the select tag.

Comment: i am using chosen prototype version, for this i need to use Event.simulate.js. I added the js file and i want call an ajax function when the select dropdown got changed. But chosen prototype i dont know much please help me.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   $("#start").change( function() { 
        alert($("#start").val()); 
    }); 
</script>

<div class="side-by-side clearfix" style="margin-bottom:14px;">
    <select  data-placeholder="Select Loacation" class="chzn-select" tabindex="2" name="source" id="start">
      <option value="">Select Loacation</option>
      <c:forEach items="${listOfRoutes}" var = "route">
      <option value="${route.source }" >${route.source }</option>
      </c:forEach>
    </select>
</div>
```